# Using apple script to press the return key when prompted to connect to server

Tags: networking, applescript, connectivity

Currently this is my delima. Once in a while a build agent will reboot. It needs to always stay connected to share on one of our servers. The idea was to tell finder to mount the volume, wait 2 seconds, and then press enter...since the user name and pssword are both part of the address when I enter it such as  `SMB://username:password@Server1/DFS` it pops up the pasword dialog fully populated but I can't get applescript to recognize it, then press either connect or the return to say "Yes" login witht hat name and don't prompt me.

it worked fine when connecting at home to a synology device but it's not working when connecting to a server in the office.

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "SMB://username:password@Server1/DFS"
delay 2

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "return" -- key code 36
```

Any help for this seemingly simple step would be greatly apprecited.

I have looked ove the forums and found variou stratagies but they all relate to an application like Firefox or some other script aware app. I just need it to press enter when the password dialog comes up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `Finder` is not needed to mount a volume, you can delete the tell block.

Secondly, if username and password are passed the volume is supposed to mount without a dialog. Maybe you could find the reason why it doesn't.

Nevertheless the password dialog belongs to the process `SecurityAgent`, you have to use (ugly) GUI scripting to press the button:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    tell window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
        click button 2
    end tell
end tell
```

The script waits until the window appeared, this is much more reliable than an hard-coded delay.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as I would expect a solution such as https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/698/204318 to work for you to directly mount the share:

```
mount -t smbfs //username:password@MACHINENAME/SHARENAME /SomeLocalFolderOfChoice
```

However, if you are really required to interact with the dialog, and as you asked about it, take a look at [this tutorial](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/) (written in Python) for scripting up something:

- detect missing connection
- attempt connection
- capture screen periodically

  - look for dialog box, else loop
  - error after a few seconds of failure
- if dialog is detected, interact with it

  - input username and password
  - wait, then press return
- check if connection worked after a small delay
- success or failure

This type of strategy is very powerful for interacting with all sorts of different dialogs you may encounter and should be possible in AppleScript if you are much more familiar with it (or another scripting language).

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to non-AppleScript solutions, then you might consider [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), one of the best Mac automation tools available.

You said:

> it pops up the pasword dialog fully populated but I can't get
>   applescript to recognize it, then press either connect or the return
>   to say "Yes" login witht hat name and don't prompt me.

You could probably do this very easily using Keyboard Maestro.  Here's an example of the KM Actions to accomplish this.

[image]

If you'd like help with KM, please visit the forum at:
https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/

I'm a big AppleScript/JXA user, but I often find it easier/quicker to use KM for many automation tasks.  Of course, KM Macros can execute AppleScript, JXA, Shell Scripts, and other scripts easily.

You can try a full version of KM for free for 30 days.